# Async function execution order vs regular function execution order

Tags: javascript

As i understand async functions will always return a promise and i can use await only inside an async function.

For my question lets take this code example:

```
async function test1(data){
//do something
await FuncReturnsPromise();
await FuncReturnsPromise2();
//do something
}
```

and the exact same function but not async:

```
function test2(data){
//do something
FuncReturnsPromise();
FuncReturnsPromise2();
//do something
}
```

Now in the second function (the regular one) if i will call it, it will start executing and when it will reach the `FuncReturnsPromise`.

It will start executing it also until it will return the promise and it will continue (in here i'm not waiting for the promise) to the second call and that's it.

Both `FuncReturnsPromise` and `FuncReturnsPromise2` execute some statements and than execute async xhr request and returns the promise, the first statements in each of those functions is vital to me and needs to be executed in an sync order.

So my question is if i can write my async function like this:

```
async function test1(data,wait){
//do something
if(wait)await FuncReturnsPromise();
else FuncReturnsPromise();
if(wait) await FuncReturnsPromise2();
else FuncReturnsPromise2();
//do something
}
```

And if i will call it like this `test1(somedata,false)`  the function will be executed as if it was a regular function? Or should i declare both async and regular functions for both of my use cases?

Answer (score 1):

It will still return a promise because it is an async function, but that returned promise will will not track the resolution of `FuncReturnsPromise();` and `FuncReturnsPromise2();`.

Comment: i don't care about the promises i just need to know if i will execute test1(somedata,false) the same instructions will be executed as if i will execute test2(somedata);

Answer (score 1):

To save you even creating a Promise, you could wrap your wait functions inside an anonymous function and return that only if the wait flag is used, otherwise just execute the functions directly.

eg.

```
function test1(data, wait){
  if (wait) {
    return (async function () {
      await FuncReturnsPromise();
      await FuncReturnsPromise2();
    }());
  } else {
    FuncReturnsPromise()
    FuncReturnsPromise2();
  }
}
```

Comment: 2 questions regarding this code, 1. if i will pass wait to the function the i will need to call it with a second () like test1(somedata,true)() to execute the returned function right? , 2. the promise your mentioned that i can avoid creating is the promise returned from the async function right? and not the one from FuncReturnsPromise

Comment: @avidahan  Updated so you don't need the `()` when calling `wait`,..   Yes, there is an extra promise created when you use `false` in your version that doesn't do anything, this avoids that.  Not that it would make a massive difference, also this avoids lots of `if else` checks too, and to me just looks a tad nicer.